# Jquery code breaking the rest of my code

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have some Jquery that I've added to a load of other Jquery (which all works fine) but it's breaking the rest of my code. There's an error in there somewhere but I just can't work out where!

```
//Retrieve the customization summary area:
var summary = $('#customise-area-3 p');

//Use jQuery to select all the checkboxes with the name hardware that are checked.
$('input[type=checkbox][name=hardware\[\]]:checked').each(function(k,v) {
    //Retrieve the value of the checkbox.
    var checkboxValue = v.val();

    //Add the checkbox value to the summary area:
    summary.innerHTML += checkboxValue + '<br />';
});
```

This is within Wordpress so all the rest of my Jquery is in the style of:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) 
{
    $("#customise").click(function()
    {
        $(".entire_product").hide();
        $(".customise").show();
    });
});
```

---

To get the code working within the Wordpress environment I've done the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) 
{
   var summary = $('#customise-area-3 p').get(0);

   $('input[type=checkbox][name="hardware[]"]:checked').each(function(k,v) {
    //Retrieve the value of the checkbox.
    var checkboxValue = v.val();

    //Add the checkbox value to the summary area:
    summary[0].innerHTML += checkboxValue + '<br />';
});
});
```

Although this stops the rest of my code from breaking, it doesn't actually do anything. I.e add the selected checkbox value to the summary.

Comment: What do you mean by "breaking"? Are you getting a run-time error, or does the code not work as you expect? If the latter, please explain exactly *how* it is working.

Comment: 1.should be `var summary = $('#customise-area-3 p').get(0);`, modify the innerHTML of a jquery object is meaningless. 2. [type=checkbox] is unnecessary. 3. why `name=hardware\[\]`? do you have any run-time error message, or a jsfiddle demo?

Comment: @RB. What I mean by breaking is that all the jquery accordians, scrollers etc on the page stop working when I put the code in the question in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly using \ slash in selector and you are using innerHTML on jQuery object which is wron

Change

```
$('input[type=checkbox][name=hardware\[\]]:checked')
```

To

```
$('input[type=checkbox][name="hardware[]"]:checked')
```

You better use wild card if you need to check name that starts with hardware

```
$('input[type=checkbox][name^=hardware]:checked')
```

Change

```
summary.innerHTML += checkboxValue + '<br />';
```

To

```
summary[0].innerHTML += checkboxValue + '<br />';
```

Comment: I've updated my question with code. That code blocks stops the rest of the jquery from breaking but the code doesn't actually do anything now. I guess that's another question.

Comment: It would be better of you put a new question  with all the required html and explanation for what you want to achieve, as this question does not have enough information.

Comment: Ok here is my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727451/step-by-step-checkbox-process-with-summary-of-selections p.s more than happy for you to update the answer with the working code in my updated question so I can mark as complete.

Answer (score 0):

your line

```
//Add the checkbox value to the summary area:
    summary.innerHTML += checkboxValue + '<br />';
```

is trying to set the innerHTML of an object, that looks to be where your code is breaking

you should use

```
summary.html(checkboxValue + '<br />');
```

there may be other errors like that in there. but that is the only one i can see

Comment: I think Wordpress is mangling the code, whenever I put this related code in, every other jquery element stops working (accordians, scrollers etc).

Comment: well then if that is the case then try `summary.get(0).innerHTML` but always make sure that `summary.length<>0` otherwise you will get an error