# Step by step checkbox process with summary of selections

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to create a 3 step process where someone selects the items they want on steps 1 and 2 via checkboxes, then on the third step it shows a summary of those selections.

This is how my html is setup:

```
<form id="customisesystem" method="post" action="">
  <div id="first-step">
    <div class="steps">
      <p><b>Step 1 of 3</b></p>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-buttons"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="customise-area">
      <div id="customise-title">
        <p><b>1. Hardware &amp; software options</b> <span>Please choose one or more of the following</span></p>
      </div>
      <div id="customise-area">
        <?php $posts = get_field('options');
                            if( $posts ):
                            $items = 0;
                            foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT)
                                setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <div class="custom-option">
          <p><b>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </b></p>
          <br />
          <div> <?php echo the_content(); ?> </div>
          <?php $counter = 1; while(the_repeater_field('images')): ?>
          <?php if($counter <= 1) { ?>
          <img width="180" height="136" src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
          <?php } ?>
          <?php $counter++; endwhile; ?>
          <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="hardware[]" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            Select</p>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <?php $items++; endforeach;
                            wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly
                            endif; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end first-step -->

  <div id="second-step">
    <div class="steps">
      <p><b>Step 2 of 3</b></p>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-buttons"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="customise-area">
      <div id="customise-title">
        <p><b>2. Accessories</b> <span>Please choose one or more of the following</span></p>
      </div>
      <div id="customise-area">
        <?php $posts = get_field('accessories');
                            if( $posts ):
                            $items = 0;
                            foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT)
                                setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <?php if ($items&1) { ?>
        <div class="custom-option">
          <p><b>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </b></p>
          <br />
          <div> <?php echo the_content(); ?> </div>
          <?php $counter = 1; while(the_repeater_field('images')): ?>
          <?php if($counter <= 1) { ?>
          <img width="180" height="136" src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
          <?php } ?>
          <?php $counter++; endwhile; ?>
          <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="accessories[]" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            Select</p>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="custom-option">
          <p><b>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </b></p>
          <br />
          <div> <?php echo the_content(); ?> </div>
          <?php $counter = 1; while(the_repeater_field('images')): ?>
          <?php if($counter <= 1) { ?>
          <img width="180" height="136" src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
          <?php } ?>
          <?php $counter++; endwhile; ?>
          <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="accessories[]" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            Select</p>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php $items++; endforeach;
                            wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly
                            endif; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end second-step -->

  <div id="third-step">
    <div class="steps">
      <p><b>Step 3 of 3</b></p>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-buttons"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="customise-area-3">
        <p>Summary</p>

        <div id="customise-area-3-child">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end third-step -->

</form>
```

This is my jquery for stepping through the process:

```
var prevLink = '<a class="back" href="#">Back</a>';
var nextLink = '</a><a class="next" href="#">Next</a>';
var navHTML = '<div class="prev-next">' +
                         prevLink +
                         nextLink +
                      '</div>';
var prevLink = '<a class="back" href="#">Back</a>';
var nextLink = '</a><a class="next" href="#">Next</a>';
var navHTML = '<div class="prev-next">' +
                         prevLink +
                         nextLink +
                      '</div>';
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
            // init
            $('#customisesystem > div')
                .hide()
                .prepend(navHTML);
            $('#first-step .prev').remove();
            $('#last-step .next').remove();

            // show first step
            $('#first-step').show();

            $('a.next').click(function(){
                var whichStep = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');

                if( whichStep == 'first-step' )
                {
                    // validate first-step
                }
                else if( whichStep == 'second-step' )
                {
                    // validate second-step
                }
                else if( whichStep == 'last-step' )
                {
                    // validate last-step
                }

                $(this).parent().parent().hide().next().show();
            });

 $('a.back').click(function(){
          var whichStep = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
          if(whichStep == "first-step"){
            $(".customise").hide();
            $(".entire_product").show();
          }
          else{
            $(this).parent().parent().hide().prev().show();
          }
 });
        });
```

---

Here's the part that isn't working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) 
{
   var summary = $('#customise-area-3 p').get(0);

   $('input[type=checkbox][name="hardware[]"]:checked').each(function(k,v) {
    //Retrieve the value of the checkbox.
    var checkboxValue = v.val();

    //Add the checkbox value to the summary area:
    summary[0].innerHTML += checkboxValue + '<br />';
   });
});
```

At the moment, when I've made the hardware selections and goto the third step it doesn't show any information in the summary. Where am I going wrong?

Here's the working link - [teamworksdesign.com/clients/rogue/system/dc-stimulator](http://teamworksdesign.com/clients/rogue/system/dc-stimulator) click on "get quotation" on the right. That will show step 1, click next for step 2, then next for step 3 (i.e the summary).

Comment: Have you debugged if `$('input[type=checkbox][name="hardware[]"]:checked').length` returns a value more than 0 ?

Comment: @Omid I'm not entirely sure. Here's the working link - http://www.teamworksdesign.com/clients/rogue/system/dc-stimulator/ click on "get quotation" on the right. That will show step 1, click next for step 2, then next for step 3 (i.e the summary).

Comment: I cannot use jQuery on console. Seems there is a confiliction

Comment: `var checkboxValue = v.val();`? Surely this statement will throw an error.

Comment: Why is the last bock of code sitting, isolated, inside a `$(document).ready(...)` structure? Should it not be a function callable from step 3?

Comment: `parent().parent()` (several times) can (and generally should) be avoided by using jQuery's [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: Managing the sequence in steps may be a bad idea. With this type of thing it's typically easier and more user-friendly (a) to have the entire interface visible at all times and (b) have a function that reads the entire interface and responds accordingly. At such time that the interface is not yet complete enough for a response (summary) to be formulated, then a suitable message (or blank) should be displayed. Thus, "steps" are things that may still occur, but they disappear from the code.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Are there any kind of code examples I can try to rule things out? Admittedly, I'm not the best at jquery so there's probably better ways to do things. The one thing I can't avoid is to have steps, this is a client request so there isn't a way around this.

Comment: Rob, I'm not suggesting that you should purge steps, rather that the interface could be managed to lead the user through the various stages without needing to test "whichstep" in the way that you currently do. A classy approach would be to use jQuery UI's `.dialog()`. I can't promise but will try to find time later this evening to construct a demo for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things get easier if the "step" divs are all given `class="step"`, thus allowing them to be selected with `jQuery(".step")`, and avoiding the need for each one to have a unique id.

Your specific question is answered by including, in the last step, a "Validate" button, which performs the validation. If the last step is valid :

- Summary text is created and displayed
- The "Validate" button is hidden and a "Submit" button is shown.

This last feature ensures that the form can't be submitted until the last step is validated
and that the user can read the Summary before the screen is refreshed.

Here's the code (laced with comments) :

```
//create nav wrapper
var $nav = $('<div/>').addClass('prev-next');

//create Prev button, attach click handler and append to nav wrapper
$('<a class="prev" href="#">Back</a>').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest(".step").hide().prev(".step").show();
}).appendTo($nav);

//create Next button, attach click handler and append to nav wrapper
$('<a class="next" href="#">Next</a>').on('click', function () {
    var $step = $(this).closest(".step");
    if (validate($step)) {
        $step.hide().next(".step").show();
    }
}).appendTo($nav);

//In one long jQuery chain ...
//* prepend nav to each step div
//* hide all steps except the first
//* convert first 'Back' link and last 'Next' link to spans.
$(".step").prepend($nav).hide()
    .filter(":first").show().find("a.prev").after('<span>Back</span>').remove().end().end()
    .filter(":last").find("a.next").after('<span>Prev</span>').remove();

//Last step doesn't have a "Next" button but does have a "Validate" button
//and a submit button, which is hidden until the last step is validated,
//thus allowing the Summary message to be shown.
//Otherwise, the summary message would appear only for a brief moment.
var $validateButton = $("#validate").on('click', function() {
    if( validate( $(".step:last") ) ) {
        //var summary = [];
        var summary = ["Test Message"];//for debugging
        $('input[type=checkbox][name="hardware[]"]:checked').each(function(i, ch) {
            summary.push($(ch).val());
        });
        $('#customise-area-3 p').html(summary.join('<br/>'));
        $(this).hide();
        $("input[name='submit']").show();
    }
});

//Unfortunately, hidden form elements are not inlcuded in the submission,
//so all steps must be shown before the form is submitted.
var $submitButton = $("input[name='submit']").on('submit', function() {
    $(".step").show();
    return true;
});

function validate($step) {
    //var valid = false;
    var valid = true;//for debugging

    //Set the last section's validate and submit buttons to their "unvalidated" states.
    $validateButton.show();
    $("input[name='submit']").hide();

    //Perform validation
    switch ($step.index(".step")) {//index-origin is zero
        case 0:
            //validate step 1 here
            //if valid, set `valid` to true 
        break;
        case 1:
            //validate step 2 here
            //if valid, set `valid` to true 
        break;
        case 2:
            //validate step 3 here
            //if valid, set `valid` to true 
        break;
    }
    return valid;//Important - determines behaviour after validate() returns.
}
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/za3Nk/5/)

You will see that I made some other minor modifications to the HTML, in particular to add the Validate button in the last step.

### EDIT

If the last step is solely for displaying the Summary and requires no validation of its own, then things are simpler :

```
//Create nav wrapper
var $nav = $('<div/>').addClass('prev-next');

//Create Prev button, attach click handler and append to nav wrapper
$('<a class="prev" href="#">Back</a>').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest(".step").hide().prev(".step").show();
}).appendTo($nav);

//Create Next button, attach click handler and append to nav wrapper
$('<a class="next" href="#">Next</a>').on('click', function() {
    $('#summary_text').html(makeSummary());
    var $step = $(this).closest(".step");
    if (validate($step)) {
        $step.hide().next(".step").show();
    }
}).appendTo($nav);

//In one long jQuery chain ...
//* prepend nav to each step div
//* hide all steps except the first
//* convert first 'Back' link and last 'Next' link to spans.
var $steps = $(".step").prepend($nav).hide()
    .filter(":first").show().find("a.prev").after('<span>Back</span>').remove().end().end()
    .filter(":last").find("a.next").after('<span>Prev</span>').remove().end().end();

//Set step titles
$steps.each(function(i, step) {
    $(step).find(".step-title").text('Step ' + (i+1) + ' of ' + $steps.length);
});

//Unfortunately, hidden form elements are not inlcuded in the submission,
//so all steps must be shown before the form is submitted.
var $submitButton = $("input[name='submit']").on('submit', function() {
    $steps.show();
    return true;
});

function validate($step) {
    //var valid = false;
    var valid = true;//for debugging

    //Perform validation
    switch ($step.index(".step")) {//index-origin is zero
        case 0:
            //Validate step 1 here
            //if valid, set `valid` to true 
        break;
        case 1:
            //Validate step 2 here
            //if valid, set `valid` to true 
        break;
        case 2:
            //No validatation required
        break;
    }
    return valid;//Important - determines behaviour after validate() returns.
}

function makeSummary() {
    var summary = [];
    $steps.not(":last").each(function(i, step) {
        $step = $(step);
        summary.push('<h4>' + $step.data('name') + '</h4>');
        var $ch = $step.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
        if(!$ch.length) {
            summary.push('<p>No items selected</p>');
        }
        else {
            $ch.each(function(i, ch) {
                summary.push('<p>' + $(ch).val() + '</p>');
            });
        }
    });
    return summary.join('');
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/za3Nk/7/)

In the demo, you will find further mods to the HTML and CSS.

Notes :

- Unless I've missed something, the javascript should now be automatically responsive to more/less steps. So if the customer was to change his mind and wanted to split Hardware and software into separate steps, you would only need to change the HTML. (Oh yes, and the `validation()` function - that is a special case).
- The "Step X of Y" text is now automatically generated and requires just `<h2 class="step-title"></h2>` in the HTML.
- Now requires a `data-name` attribute in the first and second step divs. This is used in the Summary.
- The summary is formatted; uses `<p>` elements instead of `<br>`; includes `<h4>` section headers.
- "Validate" button now removed from the last step.
- Various additional/modified CSS directives.

Comment: That's great, thanks. Is there a way to do it without the validation step? I just want them to get to the 3rd step and it to just show what they had selected, then have the submit button.

Comment: Rob, yes I was working on that even before you posted, just in case the the last step doesn't require any validation of its own. See my edit (and revised Demo) above.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comprehensive answer and help. I'll give this a go now and see if I can integrate it with what I have.

Comment: Yes, you can have fun weaving my HTML into your PHP.

Comment: It's working within my environment, much easier than I thought. Once again thanks very much!! Brilliant!!

Comment: I've now got a new request, quantity inputs next to each accessory. I've created a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858495/show-user-inputs-on-a-summary-page), is there any chance you could help? You did such a rock solid job on the original question.