# Tie two inputs together (text & hidden)?

Tags: php, html

I have a loop below that is showing a quantity box and includes a hidden field containing the product name.

I want these to be tied together so if out of 100 inputs the user changes the quantity of input 90, then and want the hidden field input 90 to be tied to it.

This then gives me the quantity and the product name for items that have more than zero.

```
<?php if(get_field('sizes')) {
while(the_repeater_field('sizes')) { ?>
   <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="0"> <?php the_title(); ?>
   <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<?php } } ?>
```

I want to tie these two together so it would echo out the following:

- 1 x Product One
- 10 x Product Three
- 20 x Product Eight

How can I output the quantity AND product name only if the quantity is more than zero?

---

This is the actual code used:

```
    <?php if(get_field('sizes')) { ?>
    <?php while(the_repeater_field('sizes')) { ?>
        <tr>    
            <td width="150"><p><?php echo the_sub_field('size'); ?></p></td> 
            <td width="30" align="right">
                <p>
                    <input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" style="width:15px;text-align:center!IMPORTANT;margin-left:10px;" value="0">
                    <input type="hidden" class="productinput" name="product[]" value="<?php echo the_title(); ?> - <?php echo the_sub_field('size'); ?>"></td>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <tr>            
            <td width="150"><p>Quantity</p></td>
            <td width="30" align="right">
                <p>                
                    <input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" style="width:15px;text-align:center!IMPORTANT;margin-left:10px;" value="0"><?php echo the_sub_field('size'); ?>
                    <input type="hidden" class="productinput" name="product[]" value="<?php echo the_title(); ?>">
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr> 
    <?php } ?>
```

This is then creating the code ready to be output in an email:

```
$quantities = array_combine($_POST['product'], $_POST['quantity']);
foreach ($quantities as $product => $quantity) {
    if ($quantity > 0) {
        $productresults = "$quantity x $product";
    }
}
```

---

[This](http://www.teamworksdesign.com/clients/rogue/system/dc-stimulator/) is the page I'm working on. If you click on "Get Quotation", the second step is the code above.

---

@Sn0opy

```
foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $check) {
    if($check > 0) {
        $quantityresults .= $check."\n";
    }
}

echo $quantityresults;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously need to iterate over both arrays in tandem so that you can see if a product's quantity is nonzero in order to decide if it should be displayed.

In general `foreach` is an awkward tool for this job, and the way to go is with a `for` loop and indexing into both arrays using the same counter. However, in this specific case you can easily transform your two arrays into one where the keys are product names and the quantities are the values using [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$quantities = array_combine($_POST['product'], $_POST['quantity']);
```

You can then easily iterate with `foreach`:

```
foreach ($quantities as $product => $quantity) {
    if ($quantity > 0) {
        echo "$quantity x $product<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though I had filled in "1" for several of the inputs it only actually output the last product I filled in.

Comment: @Rob: This should work fine. If it doesn't that means the contents of `$_POST` are not quite what one expects to see based on the code you posted. Do multiple products have the same name?

Comment: All the names are unique. I've updated my question with the actual code used just in case there's something stupid in there.

Comment: @Rob: You 'll have to do some basic debugging on this. Read the description of `array_combine` then `print_r($_POST)` and `print_r($quantities)`. At that point it should be obvious what the problem is.

Comment: @Rob: Pretty much anywhere will do. You are only interested in `$_POST` which is there from the get go and `$quantities`.

Comment: When running through each loop separately it shows all the correct product names and quantities, I just can't get them to work together.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the product ID in the quantity array like this:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity[<?php the_title(); ?>][]" value="0">
```

Ofc, this is not the answer you were looking for, but an alternate version which should also work.

Comment: How would I reference that to output the results? Would that make the name unique? I need it to be the same.

Comment: Well, this way you reference with the exact name, in this case the output of `the_title()`. I recommend using product IDs instead, because your product title could contain characters which makes referencing via `$_POST['quantity']['my weird @@product@@ name!!']` really complicated for example.

Comment: I can't get it to output the name of the product using this method. I'll update my question with the code.

Comment: Surely there's a way to merge the two arrays and match the rows?

Answer (score 1):

Rob, I see you have a good answer but you might like to be aware of a significant issue.

By posting independent `quantities[]` and `products[]`, then you are relying on the two serializations being conformal with each other - ie. that both are serialized in DOM order - hence that the indexes of `$_POST['quantity']` and `$_POST['product']` correspond element-by-element. For me, this is not a completely safe assumption - see the selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400698/is-the-order-of-inputs-in-a-post-guaranteed-for-array-inputs-in-php).

It would be far safer, and more conventional, to have one `<input>` field per product, named with a representation of product-id and a value representing quantity. Thus, product-ids and their values are guaranteed to correspond.

Client-side and server-side code would need to be reviewed accordingly.