# Using array_combine to show user input results

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using `array_combine` to show the results of some user choices.

This is my loop:

```
<?php if(get_field('sizes')) { ?>
<?php while(the_repeater_field('sizes')) { ?>
    <?php echo the_sub_field('size'); ?>
    <input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" class="productinput" name="product[]" value="<?php echo the_title(); ?> - <?php echo the_sub_field('size'); ?>">
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

This is how I'm then outputting the results

```
$quantities = array_combine($_POST['product'], $_POST['quantity']);
foreach ($quantities as $product => $quantity) {
    if ($quantity > 0) {
        $productresults = "$quantity x $product";
    }
}
echo $productresults;
```

At the moment it only outputs the last input quantity and product name. E.g if I change 5 inputs then it only shows the 5th.

What am I missing to show all the inputs that were changed?

Comment: u r missing the .(Dot) for concatenating the result

Comment: $productresults .= "$quantity x $product"; or just print the result like echo $productresults = "$quantity x $product";

Comment: Is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872227/tie-two-inputs-together-text-hidden in disguise again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code, the problem was you are outputing `$productresults` after `foreach` loop,and because of that it echoes last value assigned.

```
$productresults = "";
$quantities = array_combine($_POST['product'], $_POST['quantity']);
foreach ($quantities as $product => $quantity) {
    if ($quantity > 0) {
        $productresults .= "$quantity x $product ";
    }
}
echo $productresults;
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason why I had the echo outside the loop was because I want to echo it into an email script that gets sent to myself. Is there a way to put all the data into a variable and then just echo that variable into my email script?

Comment: @Rob see the edited answer. In this it will concatenate all result in single string. And you can use that variable for output.

Answer (score 0):

save your result in an array.

```
   $quantities = array_combine($_POST['product'], $_POST['quantity']);
    foreach ($quantities as $product => $quantity) {
        if ($quantity > 0) {
            $productresults[] = "$quantity x $product";
        }
    }
    print_r($productresults);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$quantities      = array_combine($_POST['product'], $_POST['quantity']);
$productresults  = array();
foreach ($quantities as $product => $quantity) {
    if ($quantity > 0) {
        $productresults[] = $quantity x $product;
    }
}

echo implode(",", $productresults); // implode it with any thing you need.
```

Comment: @rob : This will give you better option to join your strings.